# NetBeans / Java Launch Error

Tags: java, netbeans

When I launch NetBeans (version 6.7.1) I get an error:

http://78.46.92.11/errors/netbeans-launch-error.jpg

It is the first time when I see it. I haven't had problems like this one before. It's the first time when I open NB and see such error.

Also, when I try to open a project I get another error:

http://78.46.92.11/errors/netbeans-open-project-error.jpg

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Gabriel

Comment: "Click Show Details for the stack trace."

Comment: Here's what I get when I click "Show Details". It's long to paste here so I've created a screenshot:

http://78.46.92.11/errors/netbeans-show-details.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a broken installation to me. I'd suggest uninstalling and reinstalling.

Alternatively, it may just be one plug-in which is hosed - have you installed any new ones recently? As Bill says, "Show Details" may help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't remember installing any new plugin. I have just opened NetBeans and surprisingly I have seen these errors.

http://78.46.92.11/errors/netbeans-show-details.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported some setting from previous version during 6.7.1 installation? (NetBeans offers such option)

There may be problem in your userdir. See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir and try running NB with clean userdir.

Anyway, feel free to report those problems by the "Review and Report" button. The bugtracking system will recognize whether it is a new problem, or problem already solved.